# How to change print preferences when using MailItem.PrintOut in VSTO

Tags: c#, printing, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to automatically print the first page of all incoming emails from a VSTO addin.
Formatting has to be preserved so, as far as I know, calling MailItem.PrintOut() is my only route as far as the actual printing is concerned.
Here's where I am so far.

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
/*
...
*/
private void ProcessMailItem(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
        PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.AllowSomePages = true;
        pd.AllowSelection = true;
        ps.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
        ps.FromPage = 1;
        ps.ToPage = 2;
        //ps.MinimumPage = 1;
        //ps.MaximumPage = 2;
        mailItem.PrintOut();
}
```

The settings are ignored and the email is printed using the default settings.

The solution I temporarily went with was sending keys to get to the printing preferences but I'd like to change it if possible.

```
private void ProcessMailItem(Outlook.MailItem mailItem)
{
  SendKeys.Send("%f");
  SendKeys.Send("p");
  SendKeys.Send("r");
  /*
  TABing to page selection
  TABing to OK
  */
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook provides no means to change any printer settings. You will be better off exporting a message in the DOC / HTML /RTF format, opening the file programmatically in Word, and printing it there.